# Don't understand encoding ANSI to UTF8

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, hex, ansi, iso-8859-1

I have the following text in Notepad++ which is in "ANSI" encoding:

```
VallÃ©s, Ramon Casas
```

When I tell Notepad++ to "encode in UTF8" it displays as:

```
Vallés, Ramon Casas
```

The two characters `Ã©` are `c3a9` in Hex.  How can they become an `é` in UTF8 which is `e9`?

Comment: Did you type that text into Notepad++ or did you open an existing text file in Notepad++ and not correct its erroneous guess at what the file's encoding is?

Comment: I copied and pasted from a web page when the browser's encoding is set to "Western".  I'm just trying to understand the encoding issue.

Comment: Which did you copy, "VallÃ©s, Ramon Casa" or "Vallés, Ramon Casas"?

Comment: The first one. If you change the browser's encoding to 'Unicode' it displays the second one.

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the browser encoding 99.99% of the time. It follows HTTP rules and if missing then HTML rules and if missing then it guesses. Was there a problem there? What was the HTTP response Content-Type header? Use the browser's F12 Dev Tools.

Comment: The bytes `c3 a9` *are* `é` in UTF-8.  Your assumption that `é` is `e9` is incorrect and is actually the correct encoding for `iso-8859-1` and, more likely, `Windows-1252`.

Comment: "The two characters Ã© are c3a9 in Hex": True for Windows-1252, windows-1254, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-9, iso-8859-15; not true for the other 135 encodings on my system. "é … is e9": True for 13 character encodings; not true for 127.